# How to avoid circular dependencies when manipulating a reactive collection that you observe?

Tags: meteor, reactive-programming

I run an `autorun` loop each time an item is added to my collection. But I have also to delete this item in the same code block. So I end with an infinite autorun loop.

```
$meteor.autorun($scope, function(){
    var traces = Traces.find().fetch();
    _.each(traces, function(trace){
        console.log(trace.coordinates);
        //remove local trace. Server one is already erased.
        Tracker.nonreactive(function(){
            Traces.remove({_id:trace._id});
        });
    });
});
```

I tried to put the remove code in a nonreactive function but it does not work and the code run in loop.

How can I pause/enable the reactiveness of a dependency?

Comment: Why are you having to remove local traces if they are already deleted on the server? That deletion should propagate automatically to mini-mongo.

Comment: It does not propagate because I only observe 'added' in my publish function on the server.
It is a kind of stream. Data is sent to the client and are deleted from the server.
Then the client receives the data, treats it, and deletes it too.

Comment: Maybe an autorun is not the best fit. Instead try a client-side observer where the callback to added() removes the incoming trace by id.

Comment: @JeremyS. I have just tried this but this is the same thing as observer are also an autorun block.

Comment: what happens if you do (client side) Traces.find().observeChanges({added: function(id){ Traces.remove(id); }})? This shouldn't have the circularity of the code you posted.

Comment: Yes it has the same circular dependencies. This is weird because this means added function is triggered when a document is removed from the collection...

Comment: and just to confirm, you have not wrapped the observe in an autorun?

Comment: Yep I confirm. I have also check the Traces.allow auth and all is fine.
I am investigating on server/client synchronisation. I wonder if meteor recreates some doc because it tries to delete it on the server.

Comment: No, I tried without deleting the doc on the server but the circular dependencies is still here. It is like that meteor recreates the doc just after I delete it.

Comment: Yes I think it is viewing your client collection as out of sync with the server collection and resending the doc down the wire. What if you tried getting rid of all the client side code and putting the Traces.remove() in the added() function of your server side publication

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94497/discussion-between-danieln-and-jeremy-s).